# Xamarin Forms with Dynamic Splash Screen

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a Xamarin Forms application to run on Android and iOS.  The Application itself is customised for a specific customer the first time it is run so downloads a custom splash screen and other customer specific data.

I have followed some advice on creating a splash screen in Android by adding a new SplashActivity and setting it as MainLauncher.  This activity is derived from 'Activity' as below:

public class SplashActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

```
        // Set our view 
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.splash);

        // Initialise Xamarin Essentials
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, bundle);
        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

        // If we have a splash screen already downloaded then we can try and load that here otherwise we use the default image.
        try
        {
            string splashScreen = SharedPreferences.Splash();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(splashScreen) || !File.Exists(splashScreen))
            {
                var iv = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ivSplash);
                iv.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.splash);
            }
            else
            {
                var bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(splashScreen);
                var bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
                FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ivSplash).SetImageDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ivSplash).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.splash);
        }

        // Set a timer to continue
        var timer = new Timer(2000) {AutoReset = false};
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();
    }
```

When the timer fires it calls the original MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivityBase
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        LoadApplication(new MainApp());
    }
}
```

My issue is that the App crashes with a null reference exception when I call LoadApplication.  I have set breakpoints in MainApp.xaml.cs (as this is in the portable code) and it all seems to run correctly.  It was working correctly before I added the splash screen so I assume it is down to this.

Comment: In your splash activity, add this after base.Oncreate():
StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
May be this solve your issue.

Comment: [Ref:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen) Try setting ActivityAttributes MainLauncher=true and NoHistory=true on the SplashActivity and removing MainLauncher attribute from the MainActivity.